# Combine two pandas Data Frames (join on a common column)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, left-join

I have 2 dataframes:

restaurant_ids_dataframe

```
Data columns (total 13 columns):
business_id      4503  non-null values
categories       4503  non-null values
city             4503  non-null values
full_address     4503  non-null values
latitude         4503  non-null values
longitude        4503  non-null values
name             4503  non-null values
neighborhoods    4503  non-null values
open             4503  non-null values
review_count     4503  non-null values
stars            4503  non-null values
state            4503  non-null values
type             4503  non-null values
dtypes: bool(1), float64(3), int64(1), object(8)`
```

and

restaurant_review_frame

```
Int64Index: 158430 entries, 0 to 229905
Data columns (total 8 columns):
business_id    158430  non-null values
date           158430  non-null values
review_id      158430  non-null values
stars          158430  non-null values
text           158430  non-null values
type           158430  non-null values
user_id        158430  non-null values
votes          158430  non-null values
dtypes: int64(1), object(7)
```

I would like to join these two DataFrames to make them into a single dataframe using the DataFrame.join() command in pandas.

I have tried the following line of code:

```
#the following line of code creates a left join of restaurant_ids_frame and   restaurant_review_frame on the column 'business_id'
restaurant_review_frame.join(other=restaurant_ids_dataframe,on='business_id',how='left')
```

But when I try this I get the following error:

```
Exception: columns overlap: Index([business_id, stars, type], dtype=object)
```

I am very new to pandas and have no clue what I am doing wrong as far as executing the join statement is concerned.

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Related, broader topic on pandas merging in general: [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101).

Answer (score 191, accepted):

You can use **merge** to combine two dataframes into one:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.merge(restaurant_ids_dataframe, restaurant_review_frame, on='business_id', how='outer')
```

where **on** specifies field name that exists in both dataframes to join on, and **how**
defines whether its inner/outer/left/right join, with outer using 'union of keys from both frames (SQL: full outer join).' Since you have 'star' column in both dataframes, this by default will create two columns star_x and star_y in the combined dataframe. As @DanAllan mentioned for the join method, you can modify the suffixes for merge by passing it as a kwarg. Default is `suffixes=('_x', '_y')`. if you wanted to do something like `star_restaurant_id` and `star_restaurant_review`, you can do:

```
 pd.merge(restaurant_ids_dataframe, restaurant_review_frame, on='business_id', how='outer', suffixes=('_restaurant_id', '_restaurant_review'))
```

The parameters are explained in detail in this [link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging).

Comment: Your advice solved my problem. The only change I had to make was I did an inner merge instead of outer. i.e. how='inner' instead of outer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: how=inner|outer|left|right, how to merge, intersection of keys left and right|union(ALL) keys left and right|left keys only|right keys only|

Comment: Why use merge rather than join?

Answer (score 28):

Joining fails if the DataFrames have some column names in common. The simplest way around it is to include an `lsuffix` or `rsuffix` keyword like so:

```
restaurant_review_frame.join(restaurant_ids_dataframe, on='business_id', how='left', lsuffix="_review")
```

This way, the columns have distinct names. The documentation [addresses this very problem](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html#overlapping-value-columns).

Or, you could get around this by simply deleting the offending columns before you join. If, for example, the stars in `restaurant_ids_dataframe` are redundant to the stars in `restaurant_review_frame`, you could `del restaurant_ids_dataframe['stars']`.

Comment: it also says 'business_id' column overlaps, isn't it supposed to overlap since that's the column I'm creating the join on? How do I address that issue?

Comment: Hey @DanAllan I tried the join method but all I get is 4503 entries in the restaurant_ids_dataframe and zero entries in the columns belonging to the restaurant_review_frame. Could you please let me know why this is happening? I have performed a left join as you suggested using your above statement but it doesn't seem to give me any items from the restaurant_review_frame for some reason. What I am looking for is to create a dataframe with all the columns from both the dataframes,joined on business_id. I also deleted the extra columns other than business_id.

Comment: If you are still interested in resolving this, please provide example that data reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 21):

In case anyone needs to try and merge two dataframes together on the index (instead of another column), this also works!

T1 and T2 are dataframes that have the same indices

```
import pandas as pd
T1 = pd.merge(T1, T2, on=T1.index, how='outer')
```

P.S. I had to use merge because append would fill NaNs in unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

In case, you want to merge two DataFrames horizontally, then use this code:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2],axis=1, ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```