# Merging two tsv files in two directories with same name,if the file name matches the merge them based on rows in the first file using python /R

Tags: r, python-3.x, pandas

file A

```
phy     44  
chem    46 
maths   44  
biol    42
his     38
comm    40
```

file B

```
        RaK   John
Phy    45   23
chem    43  45
maths   41   90
His     38   25
Comm    48  12
geo     49   42
```

Expected output

```
            RaK
phy    44   45
chem    46  43
maths   44  41
biol    42  0
his     38  38
comm    40  48
```

I need somthing like **join(-a1 a,b)** but in python which should be able to handle huge amount of data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas Combining 2 Data Frames (join on a common column)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792918/pandas-combining-2-data-frames-join-on-a-common-column)

Answer (score 0):

1. lower strings in B's index to match A's '0' column
2. merge on index and column, use left-join (or right-join) to keep non overlapping cases and fill NA's with zeros:

   ```
   import pandas as pd

   A = pd.read_clipboard(header=None)

   B = pd.read_clipboard()

   B.index = [x.lower() for x in B.index]

   A.merge(B[['RaK']],left_on=0,right_index=True,how='left').fillna(0)

          0    1   RaK
   0   phy     44  45
   1   chem    46  43
   2   maths   44  41
   3   biol    42  0
   4   his     38  38
   5   comm    40  48
   ```