# Combine 2 dataframes share the same column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to combine two dataframes into one

df1

```
 key  columnA
  1    0
  1    1
  1    2
```

df2

```
 key columnB
  1    3
  1    5
  1    7
```

result

```
 key columnA columnB
  1    0       3
  1    1       5
  1    2       7
```

resulting dataframe's column ordering is not important

Edit: I have tried

```
 pd.merge(df1, df2, on ='key', how = 'inner')
```

it gives me a df of

```
    A  key  B
    0    1  3
    0    1  5
    0    1  7
    1    1  3
    1    1  5
    1    1  7
    2    1  3
    2    1  5
    2    1  7
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas Combining 2 Data Frames (join on a common column)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792918/pandas-combining-2-data-frames-join-on-a-common-column)

Comment: @andrew_reece, nope, i checked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `key` has the same value on every row, you'll end up with a Cartesian join because it's unclear which `1` to match on for each `key = 1`.  Instead, match with both `key` and `index`.

With:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"key":np.ones(3, dtype=int), "columnA":np.arange(3)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"key":np.ones(3, dtype=int), "columnB":np.arange(3,9,2)})
```

Merge like this:

```
df1.merge(df2, on="key", left_index=True, right_index=True)
   columnA  key  columnB
0        0    1        3
1        1    1        5
2        2    1        7
```