# Transform a dataframe with a condition of a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 data frame

the first :

id    event_type

1     event_type1

2     event_type1

3     event_type2

etc ..

the second have a type dtype('O')

I don't know what it is but i don't have column's name for this

event_type 11                                               25.3064

event_type 35                                               21.2223

event_type 34                                               02.90151

and I want to regroup event_type if percent<5 and after put this in my main principal,

thank you,

Naïma !!

Comment: *in my main df scuse me !

Answer (score 0):

Joining two dataframes on a common column can be done as described in the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792918/pandas-combining-2-data-frames-join-on-a-common-column).

For the filtering you can use something along these lines:

```
resulting_df = df[df.percent_column < 5.0]
```

where `percent_column` is the name of the column from the `df` that contains the percent value you want to filter on.