# Merge multiple dataframes in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two data frames:
`df1` as follows:

```
  col0 col1  col1.1  col3
0    a    d       1     6
1    b    e       5     7
```

And `df2` as follows:

```
  colx  coly
0    a    10
1    b    20
2    d    50
3    e    40
```

How do I combine the dataframes in-place such that the final df looks like this?

```
  col0 col1  col1.1  col3  colx coly
0    a    d       1     6   10   50
1    b    e       5     7   20   40
```

As far as I understand, the [merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792918/combine-two-pandas-data-frames-join-on-a-common-column) method in pandas merges both dataframes based on a given axis.
In this case, I want to merge them based on the value in another dataframe. What is the function I am looking for in this case?

Comment: You will not be able to get an "in place" solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `merge` chained twice:

```
mrg = df1.merge(df2, left_on='col0', right_on='colx')\
         .merge(df2, left_on='col1', right_on='colx')\
         .drop(columns=['colx_x', 'colx_y'])
```

**Output**

```
  col0 col1  col1.1  col3  coly_x  coly_y
0    a    d       1     6      10      50
1    b    e       5     7      20      40
```

Comment: I get the following error: `ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and float64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat`

Comment: Are you merging on the correct columns, so the arguments `left_on` and `right_on`. Seems like you are selecting an object/string column and a numeric/float column

Comment: I made a mistake. my bad. apologies

Answer (score 3):

You could use `map`:

```
mapper = df2.set_index('colx')['coly']
df1['colx'] = df1['col0'].map(mapper)
df1['coly'] = df1['col1'].map(mapper)

print(df1)
```

Output:

```
  col0 col1  col1.1  col3  colx  coly
0    a    d       1     6    10    50
1    b    e       5     7    20    40
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) and `get`:

```
s=df2.set_index('colx')['coly']
df1[['colx','coly']]=df1.iloc[:,:2].applymap(lambda x: s.get(x))
print(df1)
```

---

```
  col0 col1  col1.1  col3  colx  coly
0    a    d       1     6    10    50
1    b    e       5     7    20    40
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with `replace`:

```
dct = df2.set_index('colx')['coly'].to_dict()
df1['coly_x'] = df1['col0'].replace(dct)
df1['coly_y'] = df1['col1'].replace(dct)
```

Output:

```
  col0 col1  col1.1  col3 coly_x  coly_y
0    a    d       1     6     10      50
1    b    e       5     7     20      40
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method to join on the indexes:

```
df1.join([df2.iloc[0:2,1].rename('colx'),
          df2.iloc[2:,1].rename('coly').reset_index(drop=True)])
```

Elements of the desired column are extracted, subset, and renamed. The index of the second series is reset to match. Then these are joined to df1.

this returns

```
  col0 col1  col1.1  col3  colx  coly
0    a    d       1     6    10    50
1    b    e       5     7    20    40
```