# Concatenate a list of data frames not having same columns to one single data frame

Tags: python

Df 1 has columns A B C D, Df2 has columns A B D. Df1 and Df2 are in a list. How do I concatenate them into 1 df?

Or can I directly append these dfs to one single df without using a list ?

Comment: IIUC you're just looking for a merge, `Df1.merge(Df2)`

Comment: list_of_dfs=[]
    for i in cc :
        df8 = *something*
        list_of_dfs.append(df8)
print(list_of_dfs)                                                                                                                      This is how I'm generating the dfs. I want to bind those dfs by rows. One df should be added below the previous df and the whole output will be in a single df.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine two pandas Data Frames (join on a common column)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792918/combine-two-pandas-data-frames-join-on-a-common-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes you can combine them into single pandas dataframe without that much work. Sample code:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = [(1,2,3,4)]
df2 = [(9,9,9)]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2, columns=['A', 'B', 'D'])

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], sort=False)
```

Which results into:

```
>>> pd.concat([df1, df2], sort=False)
   A  B    C  D
0  1  2  3.0  4
0  9  9  NaN  9
```