# How to merge rows of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I would like to merge pandas data frame records to one single record.

**Given a dataframe like this**:

```
patient_id  gender  age admission_id    admission_type  insurance_type  language    religion    marital_status  ethnicity   diagnosis   icustay_id  length_of_stay  BUN Creatinine  Hematocrit  Non Invasive Blood Pressure diastolic   Non Invasive Blood Pressure systolic
0   2365    F   51  117027  1   2   ENGL    CATHOLIC    SINGLE  WHITE   GASTROINTESTINAL BLEED  250042  22.9776 NaN 2.1 NaN NaN NaN
1   2365    F   51  117027  1   2   ENGL    CATHOLIC    SINGLE  WHITE   GASTROINTESTINAL BLEED  250042  22.9776 44.0    NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

**Expected output**:

```
patient_id  gender  age admission_id    admission_type  insurance_type  language    religion    marital_status  ethnicity   diagnosis   icustay_id  length_of_stay  BUN Creatinine  Hematocrit  Non Invasive Blood Pressure diastolic   Non Invasive Blood Pressure systolic
0   2365    F   51  117027  1   2   ENGL    CATHOLIC    SINGLE  WHITE   GASTROINTESTINAL BLEED  250042  22.9776 44 2.1 NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: Have you tried merge? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: concat with what?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine two pandas Data Frames (join on a common column)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792918/combine-two-pandas-data-frames-join-on-a-common-column)

Comment: Check those above links..

Comment: No it doesn't. It merges in a different way.

Comment: Please look clearly, here 2 records needs to be compressed to one. In the last 5 columns are like label encoding.

Answer (score 1):

You can do `groupby` with `first` ,notice here I assume the `patient_id` is the `groupby` key

```
out = df.groupby('patient_id').first()
```

Comment: Over power. Worked like a charm.

Comment: I got to group by all columns instead and then take mean. However worked like a charm!